# How to use global variable in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Weather(){

useEffect(()=>{
    const apiCall= async ()=>{
        var appid="";
        const resp=await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=seoul&appid=${appid}`);
        console.log(resp.data);

        var temp=String((resp.data.main.temp-273)).substring(0,4);
    };
    apiCall();
},[]);

return(
    <div>
        <div className="displayTime">{temp}</div>
    </div>
);
}
export default Weather;
```

I want to use a variable called temp in the return function. But I am not sure how to declare global variables in React.
I would be truly grateful for any help.

Comment: did you try using state ? ```const [temp,setTemp] = useState(<initial value>)```

Comment: its not good to use [var], this will bring security problems or some conflicts. Use context or localStorage for persistant data. try like @HarmandeepSinghKalsi said by using state, its better for this case

Answer (score 0):

Declare **temp** as the state variable and you can use it the return method.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

function Weather(){

const [temp,setTemp] = useState("");
useEffect(()=>{
    const apiCall= async ()=>{
        var appid="";
        const resp=await axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=seoul&appid=${appid}`);
        console.log(resp.data);

        setTemp(String((resp.data.main.temp-273)).substring(0,4));
    };
    apiCall();
},[]);

return(
    <div>
        <div className="displayTime">{temp}</div>
    </div>
);
}
export default Weather;
```

Comment: I fixed it normally thanks to you ! thank you so much!!!

Comment: Glad to know that . If this helped , I hope you would not mind upvoting and accepting the answer for better visibility of the answer . Happy Learning

Answer (score 0):

The use of self defined globals in context like your example is discouraged. Your case is similar to state handling. You might create a separate module that you can import and use. Also modify in case of state handling.

```
import {temp} from './myglobals'
```